# how to pass the data from parent page to child using reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

I would want to know when we open a html page ,if it is possible to pass the details from parent to child page using reactjs.I opted to open in a html page rather than modal pop up because of heavy data to be displayed in the page.

Below is my code :

I would want the value in variable "message" to be passed to the html page i would be opening. this message can be lengthy one having more than 3000 characters.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    openModal: function () {
        var message = "hello xyz";
        window.open('../Scripts/Custom/Details.html', '', 'toolbar=no,status=0,width=548,height=325,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes');
   },

     render: function () {

     return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.openModal} >Open Modal</button>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
);
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Comment: you are not calling any component.  You are calling an independent html page where you cannot pass any data other than through routes

Comment: pass the data as props to the child component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri : could you please help me with a snippet as how to do that ?

Comment: @Maddy Where are you passing the data?

Comment: Value in is "this.prop.details" in the return section. I want it be displayed in a  new html page on click of button.

Comment: @ShubhamJain : receiving html page also loaded with reactjs

Comment: I would say you cannot send such a message to a different html page. Are you doing anything special on the page you open up that needs to be a separate page or could you just print your message in a div that you style with CSS to make it look like a popup? Example: https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO

Comment: i was able to find a way, i assigned a data to windows parameter and received the same in html page which was opened.